# re.findall() not returning any results

Tags: python, icalendar, python-re

I'm trying to parse my calendar entries in python. I've written an AppleScript that will grab the calendar entries I want and return them as a string. An example...

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook for Mac MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
X-ENTOURAGE-CFTIMEZONE:Europe/London
X-ENTOURAGE-TZID:8
BEGIN:STANDARD
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSECOND=0;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=2;BYDAY=-1SU;BYM
 ONTH=10
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
DTSTART:16011001T020000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYSECOND=0;BYMINUTE=0;BYHOUR=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYM
 ONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:16010301T010000
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
```

I have this stored in a string `cal_string`.

I now want to extract each of the VTIMEZONE elements in to it's own string and so am using re.findall() however it is returning no results...

```
my_timezones = re.findall(r'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE(.*?)END:VTIMEZONE', cal_string)
print("timezones: ", my_timezones)
```

This just prints `timezones: []`

I've tried with/without the preceeding r in the findall and that made no difference.
I've also validated the expression by running on `test_string = 'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE test test test END:VTIMEZONE'` and that correctly returned `test test test`.

Comment: I think the problem is that the data you're trying to match spans across several lines, but by default `re.findall()` only matches things on single lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`re.DOTALL` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), without it, `.` matches anything but newline ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyTWWh/1))

```py
my_timezones = re.findall(r'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE(.*?)END:VTIMEZONE', cal_string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Or inlined ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ot5AB8/1))

```py
my_timezones = re.findall(r'(?s)BEGIN:VTIMEZONE(.*?)END:VTIMEZONE', cal_string)
```